# Having issue with pattern match incorrectly validating in Yii 2

Tags: php, regex, yii, yii2

I have a bunch of validation rules within my `rules` method and all the errors seem to work, but having an issue with this one:

```
['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/', 'message' => 'Your username can only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores and dashes.'],
```

It validates, which is the incorrect behavior.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This pattern only checks first character. You need to correct it like below:

```
['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/', 'message' => 'Your username can only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores and dashes.'],
```

To make sure that Yii's matching is working, you can test it by writing `@` (for example) as first character. Then, you can see that, validation works. So the problem is with your pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Still not seeing an error message displayed.

Comment: @Brett Wow, impossible :D As I have tested on my machine first.

Comment: Hmmmmm....... maybe something else is happening. I will have more of a fiddle around and see what I can find out.

Comment: Ok, my bad. It actually *is* validating, which is why I am getting no error message. So not sure why the match is failing, at least on my system.

Comment: @Brett hmmm, have you checked your scenarios? Maybe this one is not included in your current scenario.

Comment: It doesn't have a scenario set on this one so it should be enabled for all.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad lol........ I have a regex for the password field as well and I accidentally added the regex changes to that instead of the username one; it works now haha..... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is also not working in my project. I request you to follow this below solution:

```
[['userame'],'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z]\w*$/i','message' => 'Enter Characters Only'],
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions were not working for me. This is the best thing, so give it a try:

```
['first_name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z][A-Za-z,;\"\\s]+[!?.]$/i'],
```